# Is there a command to get model/driver/ppd of existing printers for use with `lpadmin -m`?

Tags: linux, cups

I'm setting up CUPS of one server to have the same set of printers as another CUPS server. I generally live in the CLI and it's a long list of printers, so I was wondering how simple this could be made. Looking through the commands' docs, I see that I can add printers like this:

```
lpadmin -p $printer_name -E -v $printer_location -m $printer_model
```

I can get the `$printer_name`s and `$printer_location`s with:

```
lpstat -v
```

but I can't seem to find a command that will tell me the `$printer_model` of each printer. I'm tempted to just hack it by scraping `http://localhost:631` with `curl` to get the human-readable models then matching with `lpinfo -m` to get something suitable for `lpadmin -m`, but I hope there's something more conventional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no conventional command for getting the driver of an installed printer.

Here's a solution for listing `lpadmin -m` acceptable ppd specs (relative paths,`drv:///` and/or `gutenprint*://` URI's) based on meuh's suggestion to use a library:

```bsh
# hpcups and gutenprint put their version in the model names. That means
# that if you install a printer then update the drivers, the model of the
# printer won't match with those available listed by `lpinfo -m`. So, we'll
# strip the version.
strip_versions() {
  sed -E 's/(, hpcups|- CUPS\+Gutenprint).*//'
}

# Using @ as a custom field delimiter since model names have whitespace.
# `join` is to match the printers' model names with those of the available
# drivers.
join -t@ -j2 -o 1.1,2.1 \
  <(
    ruby -r cupsffi -e '
      CupsPrinter.get_all_printer_attrs.each do |name, attrs|
        puts "#{name}@#{attrs["printer-make-and-model"]}"
      end
    ' | strip_versions | sort -t@ -k2
  ) \
  <(lpinfo -m | sed 's/ /@/' | strip_versions | sort -t@ -k2) |
# We may get multiple ppd specs per printer. For a few printers, I'm
# getting a relative path from the system model directory and either a
# drv:/// uri or a gutenprint.5.3:// URI. We'll filter out all but the
# first per printer.
awk -F@ '!a[$1]++' |
# Change the @ column delimiter for whitespace and align columns.
column -ts@
```

`cupsffi` is a ruby gem that can be installed with `gem install cupsffi`.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to grep something from the ppd files in `/etc/cups/ppd/` and the (protected) file `/etc/cups/printers.conf`, but there is a Python interface `pycups` to the cups library which can talk to the server for information. For example,

```python3
#!/usr/bin/python3
import cups
conn = cups.Connection()
printers = conn.getPrinters()
for printer in printers:
    p = printers[printer]
    print(printer, p['printer-make-and-model'])
```

The returned printer dict has entries: `printer-make-and-model`
`printer-is-shared` `printer-type` `device-uri` `printer-location`
`printer-uri-supported` `printer-state-message` `printer-info`
`printer-state-reasons` `printer-state`.
I found `pycups` in the rpm package `python3-cups`.

Comment: These are good suggestions. Unfortunately, with both I'd still need to match with `lpinfo -m` to get the string that's required for `lpadmin -m`. The ppd files in `/etc/cups/ppd/` sometimes have bits of info under different keys that can help skip matching with `lpinfo -m`, but not all the info all the time. And even matching with `lpinfo -m` is not a complete solution because model names can change even though the ppd path/uri/whatever stays the same. Maybe I should make a blogpost on how surprisingly complicated this is.

Comment: Simplest solution so far (using your second suggestion but with ruby's `cupsffi` gem): `join -t@ -j2 -o 1.1,2.1 <(ruby -r cupsffi -e 'CupsPrinter.get_all_printer_attrs.each {|n, a| puts "#{n}@#{a["printer-make-and-model"]}"}' | sort -t@ -k2) <(lpinfo -m | sed 's/ /@/' | sort -t@ -k2) | column -ts@`. This can miss cases where the human-readable model name changed because of a driver update, etc. hpcups includes the package version in the model names, for instance.

Comment: I wonder if copying `/etc/cups/ppd/` between machines suffices for setting the printers up.

Comment: I'm sure you would need `/etc/cups/printers.conf` too, and possibly `/etc/printcap`, though it can regenerate that.  You should probably move your ruby solution into a answer so others can benefit from it, and it will be more readable.